# Vue3: Is it possible to register single file components using app.component(...)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Diving into vue 3, trying to add Vue to an existing asp.net core project. Since the frontend is mostly razor pages, the app isn't being mounted with a templated component that has a hierarchy of components.

```
const vueApp = createApp({});
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
vueApp.component('MyComponent', require('./components/MyComponent').default);

vueApp.mount('#app');
```

I've also tried it this way, as described in the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#local-registration):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-browser'
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue'

const vueApp = createApp({
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
});

vueApp.mount('#app');
```

I've tried every version of this. requiring MyComponent.vue, with and without the default, importing MyComponent and using it that way (instead of require), none of them work. I just continue getting [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component 'mycomponent' (Yes I did check the html coming back from the server, It's properly capitalized...not sure why the error is lower case).

MyComponent.vue looks like this:

```
<template>
    <lots of vanilla html>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    data() {
      return { some: "data" }
    },
    methods: { ... },
    mounted() { ...}
}
</script>
//no component styling
```

Am I missing something here? Or is this no longer possible? I'm using the default vue-cli webpack config, if that matters.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent'`?

Comment: Yep, no change.

Comment: What does `MyComponent` look like when you import it? Is it an actual Vue component?

Comment: Yep, it's an actual vue component. <template> section, <script> section that export default, all that jazz. I actually think I figured it out....doesn't look exactly right but I do have the component rendering. Only took 4 hours of looking at it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after rereading the docs (for what feels like the 10th time), I think I figured out the problem. It's actually not a Vue issue at all, it's my use of the Vue component.

In my asp.net core cshtml, I was referencing the component in PascalCase, like this:

```
<MyComponent />
```

Turns out this is a no no. By convention (enforced by the browser I guess), custom elements can only be referenced in the DOM using kebab-case, like this:

```
<my-component />
```

My vue app is still defining the component in PascalCase.

My main.js file is importing `MyComponent`, then passing it into the createApp options.components object.

```
const vueApp = createApp({
    components: {
        MyComponent
    }
});
```

The more you know, I guess.

Comment: if you're rendering the components run-time, you need to use kebab case for component names. You also need to use closing tags (self closing tags a re a `<no-bueno/>`)